# Visual Studio 2017 Class Library Project: Could not load file or assembly System.IO.FileSystem

Tags: c#, visual-studio, class-library

I am developing a .NETStandard Class Library in c#, and then using a .NET Framework unit test project to test it. The problem line of code is;

```
    using System.IO;

    /*
     * Returns true if @strFile points to a file on the system,
     * Otherwise Returns False
     * 
     */
    private Boolean checkFileExists(string strFile)
    {
        return File.Exists(strFile);
    }
```

It is throwing the exception: 
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO.FileSystem, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

How do I make sure the class library project can find this library?

Thanks

Comment: .net or .net core? what are exactly the project type?

Comment: Sorry I am only new to Visual Studio, so I will try to answer as best I can.
 .Net.

I have 2 projects; one is a .NET Standard Class Library where I have implemented my class, the other is a Unit Test Project (.NET Framework). My goal is to use this unit test project to help with the implementation of the Class Library, and then export the .dll of the class library to be able to use this with VBA-Excel.

Comment: Can you please add a reference to .NETStandard Class Library package to your .NET Framework unit test project application?  It is needed to get the System.IO.FileSystem assembly that is missing.

Comment: I think my issue was using a unit test project instead of a unit test application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on links below for images of the steps

[In Visual Studio, Select Tools/NuGet Package Manager/Package Manager Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNclW.png)

[enter this at nuget Command Line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KK2TY.png)

This will install the latest System.IO.FileSystem Package from Microsoft.